# Distribute unknown number of items into 2 columns using CSS grid or flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have an unknown number of child items in a container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5…</div>
</div>
```

I would like to stack these items into 2 columns such that they appear:

```
Item 1  Item 4
Item 2  Item 5
Item 3
```

I can't figure out how to do this using CSS grid without knowing the number of grid rows, or with flexbox without setting an explicit height on the container.

Could anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Comment: So you want to get this done using css `grid` only? If you're open to other ways there is a property in CSS called [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) which you should consider looking.

Comment: @mandy8055 yes, with either grid or flexbox. I don't like `column-count` here due to the way it can split content within the child items.

Comment: ok then I can think of one way using `grid` but that would require some `Javascript` to get this done which I am thinking is also not what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I don't want to use JS. If it's not possible then the fallback is to output the number of rows dynamically as a CSS custom property in the mark-up (which needs generating server-side) then use that to do `display: grid; grid-auto-flow: column; grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--number-of-rows), 1fr)`.

Comment: Makes sense. Have you  also considered using `column-count` property? Using this won't require javascript and not even CSS custom property for any dynamic calculation.

Comment: *due to the way it can split content within the child items.* --> you can avoid this using CSS. Don't reject solutions because you don't know how they works.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't want to elaborate and have to justify why I don't want to use `column-count` as that wasn't the question. It's being used for `details`/`summary` blocks so even setting the child items to `inline-block` (which I assume is your inferred 'solution') isn't desirable as the items shift column when opening/closing. Don't assume that people don't know how things work when pertaining to peripheral factors which aren't fully documented as they are not part of the question.

Comment: I don't assume anything. I consider the content inside your question where you are not talking about details or summary elements. I only see div elements. No one is in your head and for this reason we always ask people to give **clear requirements and details** if they want accurate solutions. Your comment clearly demonstrate that your question is far from describing what you want to achieve so you won't get any good answer that you can apply to your case.

Comment: Nah. The question is perfectly clear if you're able to understand English and CSS. The question itself states "using CSS grid or flexbox". The outcome can be achieved several other ways but that was not the question. The reduced case is clear and succinctly describes the requirement. The 'answer' is that it's not presently possible, which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an *obligation* of using flexbox and grid, then as far as I know, you would require the container's height (dynamically calculating it using JavaScript or a CSS custom property which you talked about).

I can think of one way to achieve this purely in CSS without any dynamic calculation or knowing the height in advance and that is by using the [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) property. With this you don't need to worry about the number of items that come in. Sharing my solution here for reference in case you're looking for a solution other than flexbox or grid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .container {
      column-count: 2; /* speciifes that the content inside the container should be divided into two columns */
      column-gap: 1rem;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .child {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      break-inside: avoid; /* ensures that each child element stays within a single column */
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5</div>
    <div class="child">Item 6</div>
    <div class="child">Item 7</div>
    <div class="child">Item 8</div>
    <div class="child">Item 9</div>
    <div class="child">Item 10</div>
    <div class="child">Item 11</div>
    <div class="child">Item 12</div>
    <div class="child">Item 13</div>
    <div class="child">So on...</div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in CSS if you have a maximum number of posibles elements

Setting styles (a lot of them) based on a quantity query can do the job:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    width: 205px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.child {
    grid-column: 1;
  eight: 30px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.child:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ .child {
    grid-column: 2;
    color: red;
}
.child:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(-n+5) ~ .child {
    grid-column: 2;
    color: blue;
}
.child:nth-child(5):nth-last-child(-n+6) ~ .child {
    grid-column: 2;
    color: green;
}
.child:nth-child(6):nth-last-child(-n+7) ~ .child {
    grid-column: 2;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5…</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
</div>
```

An alternate way of doing it with a server side added class

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    width: 205px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.child {
    grid-column: 1;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.newcol, .newcol ~ .child {
    grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
    <div class="child">Item 5…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child newcol">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
    <div class="child">Item n…</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the number of child elements is unknown.

Comment: @Dan Even if it is unknown, if there is a maximum number of elements, you can set it up  as shown. If the maximum number of elements is 50, for instance, you will need 25 CSS rules

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
let itemCount = 0;

addEventListener('click', function() {
    itemCount++;
    const newItem = document.createElement('div');
    newItem.className = 'child';
    newItem.textContent = 'Item ' + itemCount;
    container.appendChild(newItem);
});
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10px; /* Add spacing between items */
}

.child {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="w.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child">Item 1</div>
        <div class="child">Item 2</div>
        <div class="child">Item 3</div>
        <div class="child">Item 4</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        <div class="child">Item 5</div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="w.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

but i'll use the Javascript as well